# How To Stop Hair Going Down Square Shower Drain

Tags: shower, drain

My shower drain is a 3.5 x 3.5" square with largish holes. I want to keep hair from getting into the septic, so under it I have a round trap that goes in the pipe. This is effective, however it gums up all the time. What I think would be better is if the 3.5x3.5 square had a tight mesh so the hair couldn't get below it. Then that could just be wiped off instead of me having to remove it to get to the round trap.

Thus far I have not seen another 3.5x3.5 piece that could replace it and be more effective. Not that I have looked excessively.

So
- Do you think such a product exists as is ?
- would I be better off glueing or otherwise attaching some mesh over my existing 3.5x3.5 metal piece
- should I do something else ?

See attached images to see what I mean. Thanks!

[image: shower floor]
[image: drain size]
[image: under the drain]
[image: under the drain 2]

Comment: The only true answer is full body wax

Comment: Can you post a photo of the drain with the grate / cover removed?

Comment: I have added two pictures with the grate and the circular trap I put under it removed

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to trim a piece of fiberglass screen material then simply press fit it over that grate.

Overlap the sides and fold them under then press the grate back into place. When it gets too scuzzy simply throw it away. If you're hairy like me, though, this might clog up every single day.

Comment: This is a good idea.  I think it is my fallback solution if there isn't anything ready made or someone who answers who as solved this themselves

Comment: If effectiveness trumps appearance you can slip the grate into a section of pantyhose.